# Please tell me what is error in my date comparison sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me to find out error in my SQL query. I have created this query to compare dates

```
select * from Joinplans jp
where cast(convert(varchar,GETDATE(),103) AS  datetime) BETWEEN    
    CASE(convert(varchar,jp.planstartDate,103) AS datetime) AND
    CASE(convert(varchar,DATEADD(DAY,jp.planDays,jp.planstartDate),103) AS DATETIME)
```

It's giving me the error:

> incorrect near 'AS'

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: i have changed 'CASE' to 'CAST' but still giving me error :
still giving me error: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: plez tell me is it good way to compare dates in this way or if not than what is good way to compare dates in such a situation.

Comment: Why are you converting from a datetime to a varchar and then to a datetime again?

Comment: i was converting it to remove time part from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If planStartDate is actually a date, then there is no need to cast it to a character column:

```
Select ...
From Joinplans jp 
where GetDate() Between planStartDate And DateAdd(day, jp.planDays, jp.planStartDate)
```

Now, if planStartDate is storing both date and time data, then you might want to use something like:

```
Select ...
From Joinplans jp 
Where planStartDate <= GetDate()  
    And GetDate() < DateAdd(day, jp.planDays + 1, jp.planStartDate)
```

This ensures that all times on the last date calculated via the DateAdd function are included

Comment: datatype of planstartdate is smalldatetime and i am storing datetime value in which time is 00:00

Comment: but as getdate() contains time part also.. than its creates problem (not proper result)

Answer (score 3):

You wrote `case` instead of `cast` in two instances.

Comment: ohh.. thanks .. plez tell me is it good way to compare dates in this way or if not than what is good way to compare dates in such a situation

Comment: still giving me error:
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.